# maplist error?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

The following used maplist works in swi-prolog not in gprolog:

```
GNU Prolog 1.3.1
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2009 Daniel Diaz
| ?- maplist(writeln,[1,2,3]).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,maplist/2),top_level/0)
| ?-
```

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested it on my gprolog:

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.1
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Daniel Diaz
| ?- maplist(write,[1,2,3]).  
123
```

Therefore `maplist`is defined in newer versions.

Please also note that there is no `writeln` in gprolog, so if you need it, you will have to define it first.